# Most efficient shortest path algorithm on non-negative-edged graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, shortest-path

What is the most efficient shortest path algorithm performed on a graph that is not directed and only has positive edges out of these five algorithms?

1. BFS
2. DAG
3. Dijkstra
4. Floyd-Warshall
5. Bellman-Ford

So I know Dijkstra's can't be used on negative edges and has a running time of O(E * logV) where E is the number of edges and V is the number of vertices, so this would be my best guess. Is this correct?

Comment: `DAG` is not really an algorithm (it's a class of graphs) and the rest also differ in what they do: Dijkstra (in its original form) is single source to single target, Bellman-Ford is single source to all vertices and Floyd-Warshall gives you the shortest path between any two vertices.

Comment: `A*` is probably the most efficient if you can provide a good heuristic.

Comment: @piotrekg2 ...which is an informed version of Dijkstra.

Comment: These are rather different algorithms suitable for different problems, and therefore the question does not make much sense. You can try editing your question to provide a specific problem you are facing. As it is currently written, I'm voting to close it as too broad.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find the shortest path in an **unweighted** graph, BFS would be the best option, however if there are weights on the edges, and you only need to find the optimal route between a **single source** and one or many other nodes, Dijkstra would be the best option. If you need to find the shortest path between any two pairs of nodes(i.e. have **multiple sources**), the best option is Floyd-Warshall.